# React Navigation: Dismiss current stack without animation and navigate to parent stack route with animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-navigation-stack

Given two stacks like this:

```
Home
CreateCard
    CreateCardPage1
    CreateCardPage2
Card
```

The user navigates to CreateCard, steps through `CreateCardPage1` and `CreateCardPage2` and fills out the required information, then clicks a button to create a card.

After this I'd like to navigate *forward* to the `Card` route. That is, I'd like to `dismiss` the `CreateCard` stack without the back-animation, and I'd like an animation going forward to the next screen.

Can this be done? And how?